# QT QTcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr handle) not firing?

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to create a multithreaded server using Qt for the first time. Normally one would use the socket pointer returned by the `QTcpServer::nextPendingConnection()` with the socket handle already baked in - but since I'm interfacing with the connecting client on a separate thread, I need to create the socket separately using the `qintptr handle` from QTcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr handle). After a very dreary, error-packed debugging session I managed to track down the problem to the `QTcpServer::incomingConnection()` never being fired?

Has anyone had a similar problem - has something changed over recent versions Qt?

These are the ones I've tried:

- `QTcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr handle)`
- `QTcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)`
- `QTcpServer::incomingConnection(int handle)`

EDIT:

Creating instance of server:

```
TestServer *myServer = new TestServer();
myServer->initializeServer(1234);
```

Which calls:

```
void TestServer::initializeServer(quint16 port)
{

mainServer = new QTcpServer(this);

mainServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, port);

qDebug() << "Listening for connections on port: " << port;



}
```

Server is now listening. When a client connects incomingConnection(qintptr handle) is supposed to be called:

```
void TestServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor){

TestClient *client = new TestClient(this);
client->setSocket(socketDescriptor);

}
```

Which calls:

```
void TestClient::setSocket(quint16 socketDescr)
{
socket = new QTcpSocket(this);

socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescr);

connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(connected()));
connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(disconnected()));
connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()));



}
```

Called on connect() signal:

```
void TestClient::connected()
{   
qDebug() << "Client connected..."; // This debug never appears in the console, since QTcpServer::incomingConnection isn't being fired.

}
```

Comment: Please attach some of code you got error

Comment: Did you subclass QTcpServer reimplementing ```QTcpServer::incomingConnection()```? See the Threaded Fortune Server for an example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html

Comment: Yes, I have subclassed it and reimplemented it - I haven't added the Q_DECLARE_OVERRIDE macro like in the Fortune server-example. I'll give that a shot and report back.

Comment: ~~I haven't added the Q_DECLARE_OVERRIDE macro like in the Fortune server-example. I'll give that a shot and report back. ~~ - Still not working even with Q_DECL_OVERRIDE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have some errors at your code:

1. At `TestServer`  your `QTcpServer` probably aggregated, but you need to inherit it. At this case you try to override `incomingConnection()` method, but you haven't base class and you just create new `incomingConnection()`, not override.
2. You get `qintptr descriptor` variable from `incomingConnection()`, but set `quint16` type at `setSocket()` method.
3. You probably mix client of server and client of your part, which just get incoming connection and handling socket data.

I write some little example below for your understanding tcp client-server communication.

**Server part**

Main part is server themselves:

```
#include <QTcpServer>

class TestServer: public QTcpServer
{
public:
    TestServer(QObject *parent = 0);
    void incomingConnection(qintptr handle) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};
```

Just look: I don't aggragate [`QTcpServer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html), but inherited it. At this case you can override [`incomingConnection()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection) method correctly.
At constructor we just start server for listening using [`listen()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#listen) method:

```
TestServer::TestServer(QObject *parent):
    QTcpServer(parent)
{
    if (this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 2323)) {
        qDebug() << "Server start at port: " << this->serverPort();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Start failure";
    }
}
```

Then time for overriding `incomingConnection()`:

```
void TestServer::incomingConnection(qintptr handle)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << " new connection";
    SocketThread *socket = new SocketThread(handle);

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(finished()), socket, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    socket->start();
}
```

I create `SocketThread` object which handle incoming data:

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>

class QTcpSocket;

class SocketThread: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SocketThread(qintptr descriptor, QObject *parent = 0);
    ~SocketThread();

protected:
    void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private slots:
    void onConnected();
    void onReadyRead();
    void onDisconnected();

private:
    QTcpSocket *m_socket;
    qintptr m_descriptor;
};
```

We inherits from [`QThread`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) for making our server multithreading, so we have to override [`run()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) method:

```
SocketThread::SocketThread(qintptr descriptor, QObject *parent)
    :  QThread(parent), m_descriptor(descriptor)
{

}

void SocketThread::run()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    m_socket = new QTcpSocket;
    m_socket->setSocketDescriptor(m_descriptor);

    connect(m_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),    this, SLOT(onReadyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(m_socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(onDisconnected()), Qt::DirectConnection);

    exec();
}
```

This way we initialize our [`QTcpSocket`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html), set socket descriptor, connect it with [`readyRead()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) and [`disconnected()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#disconnected) signals and start event loop.

```
void SocketThread::onReadyRead()
{
    QDataStream in(m_socket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);

    QString message;
    in >> message;
    qDebug() << message;

    m_socket->disconnectFromHost();
}

void SocketThread::onDisconnected()
{
    m_socket->close();
    // Exit event loop
    quit();
}
```

At `onReadyRead()` just read some `QString` from client, write it to console and disconnect from host. At `onDisconnected()` we [close](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#close) socket connection and exit event loop.

**Client part**

It is just example and bad-smells style, but i create connection to the server at `MainWindow` class on `QPushButton::clicked` signal:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QTcpSocket *client = new QTcpSocket;
    connect(client, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connected()));
    connect(client, SIGNAL(disconnected()), client, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    client->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 2323);
    client->waitForConnected();

    if (client->state() != QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState ) {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << " can't connect to host";
        delete client;
        return;
    }
    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);
    out << QString("Hello");
    out.device()->seek(0);
    client->write(block);
}

void MainWindow::connected()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << " client connected";
}
```

I create new `QTcpSocket`, connect it to the signals and try to connect to the host(in my case it is localhost). Wait for connected and check socket status. If all is right I write to socket `QString` - just example.

It is one of possible ways to organized multithreading client-server architecture, i hope it will be helpfull for you and you find yours bugs.

Comment: @t3ft3l--i what would be the reason if it's implemented like you suggested, but `incommingConnection()` never gets fired?

Comment: @user3085931 make for sure: 1) your server start correctly 2) client connect to server with proper ip/port 3) Some firewalls or antivirus are not blocking network communication between client and server. It is really hard to do something wrong at server side - implemetation is pretty simple and clear. I suppose, you have some problems with client connection or firewall/antivirus blockers

Comment: @t3ft3l--i well the server is listening to the right Port and to *any* IP. The client itself is able to connect ( according to the `SIGNAL(connected())`) that's the strange behaviour